# Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

We are facing this issue in our URL while accessing the Result from the server on the Flex Application on a WAS Machine.
The behavior is a bit varied when we access it on IE6 and IE7(both IEs are having same flash Player version).

IE6 doesn’t work at all but IE7 works for some conditions.
On Windows machine it is working fine(in IE6 and IE7).

Error:

> > [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: "]

If anybody has encountered this error or has dealt with it, Please respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this site: http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

Comment: But I am able to connect to the URL servlet, the logic is done and I am able to return the correct response back, but instead of Event.COMPLETE, i am getting IOErrorEvent at the Flex side.